# Comparing vectors on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

Say I have two points on the surface of a sphere $p_1$ and $p_2$. To each point, I have two unitary vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ (not necessarily tangent). I want to find the alignment between $v_1$ and $v_2$. I understand that I can't just take the scalar product $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$ as I am in a curved geometry. So I want to ask how I need to transport, say, the first vector onto the second to properly compare them. Thanks

Comment: If the vectors are not necessarily tangent to the sphere, what purpose does the sphere serve ?

Comment: The inner products is defined in curvilinear coordinate systems, you just use the right metric to describe your space.

Comment: @Triatticus The OP's problem is a bit more subtle than that, the case is not one merely of curvilinear coordinates, but of curved geometry.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus, I guess it should be clarified a tiny bit then, referencing curved geometry isn't exactly the same thing as being confined to the surface of a sphere, Schwarzschild geometry refers to a curved geometry and it does allow for an inner product.

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, the point should be clarified, curved geometries with a *Riemannian* metric do indeed admit for inner products, the OP's example is one such manifold. On the other hand, the Schwarzschild geometry and other *Lorentzian* or, "pseudo-Riemannian", manifolds allow for the *Lorentzian* inner product, which lacking positive definiteness, is not a true inner product after all.

Comment: But the main issue is that the inner product (the metric) acts in the tangent space of a point.  You cannot take the inner product of two tangent vectors that live in different tangent spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The two-sphere, i.e. $S^2$ is an example of a *smooth manifold* and the thing about smooth manifolds is that the usual notions of vectors are naturally lacking because of the decidedly non-linear properties of manifolds like $S^2$. Spaces like Euclidean manifolds are "flat" and therefore linear and one can say that the points in such a space are elements of the n-dimensional vector space known as $\mathbb{R}^n$ The surface of a sphere is does not allow for a natural notion of vector addition, and is therefore not a vector space. However, not all is lost, manifolds are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus have topological properties that are well suited to developing a notion of displacement without intrinsic vector space structure.

Despite these shortcomings, manifolds do allow for the additional structure of the inner product. Because vector and tensor fields may be locally defined on a smooth manifold via the tangent space one can define the metric tensor field $g(u,v)$, a bilinear mapping of two vectors $u=u^\alpha e_\alpha(p)$ and $v^\alpha e_\alpha(p)$ to the reals for any point $p\in\mathcal M$. This is the best that can be done because the curvature of non-linear manifolds does not allow for a definition based on parallel transport as in the Euclidean case, i.e. differing transport paths produce different results and thus any attempt at defining an inner product in that fashion would be non-unique.

Comment: $g(u,v):\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{M}\mapsto\Bbb{R}$ is wrong notation (the $\mathcal{M}$ should be $T\mathcal{M}$ and the $\times$ a $\oplus$ and $\mapsto$ a $\to$)… I would just leave it in words like you did, because that’s clearer anyway :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

Reinterpret the two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ on the surface of the sphere as 3D points, which means they correspond to two unit vectors $ \vec{p}_1$ and $ \vec{p}_2$. Form the unit vector $\vec{a} = \frac{1}{\|\vec{p}_1 \times \vec{p}_2\|} \,\, \vec{p}_1 \times \vec{p}_2$. Perform a 3D rotation $R_{\vec{a}}$ with axis $\vec{a}$ and angle such that $p_1$ is rotated to $p_2$. Then the vector $\vec{v}_1$ at point $p_1$ is rotated to vector $R_{\vec{a}}(\vec{v}_1)$ at point $p_2$. Take the dot product $\langle R_{\vec{a}}(\vec{v}_1), \vec{v}_2\rangle$.

Geometrically, this is the same as decomposing $\vec{v}_1$ at $p_1$ into a tangent and normal components, then, by using the parallel transport on the round sphere along the geodesic that connects $p_1$ to $p_2$, parallel transporting the tangent component of $v_1$ at $p_1$ to a tangent vector at $p_2$, transporting the normal component as a normal vector of constant magnitude from $p_1$ to $p_2$, and then reassembling the resulting 3D vector as the sum of the parallel-transported tangent component and the transported normal component. This most likely can be considered as parallel transport on the 3D bundle, which is the sum of the tangent bundle and the normal bundle, over the 2D sphere.